# Android application, listening to streaming radio. No internet or mobile data bug

Tags: android, streaming, media-player, internet-radio

http://pastebin.com/G4UrTT7Z

What can I do to check for a working internet connection?
Or how do I check if connection is lost?

Can someone help me with this ?

I suppose this is a IOException. I am not sure. When watching logcat and console I don't see any exceptions or forcecloses.

My source code is posted on pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to read a well known site content with URL connection. If you can read it, then it means you have an Internet connection.
Other is to connect to your radio station site: this has double requirement: you have Internet connection AND the radio station site is up.

Maybe both of them will block you, if you read too often!

There is android buggy API to read the network state and suck, but if you connect to WIFI , then you will have the Connected state from API even if your WAN cable pulled out...

Comment: Well a nice workaround is if I can use the button to stop playing the stream. When the internet is disabled and I press the Play button it seems to be stuck showing stop. And I cannot press it again to disable it.

I noticed some listeners like OnErrorListener, but they do not seem to be working at all.